# Url.Content() in Style Sheet?

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have a CSS class that references a background image :

```
#content-wrapper
{
    background: #f7f7f7 url('/Images/bg04.png');
    border-top: solid 1px #fff;
    padding: 45px 0 45px 0;
}
```

I've been using MVC4 with Razor for a little while now, and I've gotten used to using `@Url.Content()` to link to images, other pages, and also documents available on the site.

However, it doesn't look like this particular helper (or any really) is available outside of `.cshtml` pages.

**My Question** :

Is there any way to "enable" the use of `@Url.Content()` on a style sheet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I come across this and it helped me out

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="description" content="The content description" />
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="@Url.Content("~/Content/images/favicon.ico")" />
    <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
    @RenderSection("css", false)
</head>
```

Then in your Index.cshtml use the section to add your css link:

```
@section css {
    <link href="@Url.Content("~/css/style.css")" rel="stylesheet"/>
}
```

Note that "css" is a unique name for your section and it needs to match. You can also use this section in any view you want. The part you specify within the css section will then be rendered within the head-tag of your html, just where you put the RenderSection placeholder in your _Layout.cshtml.

Comment: Interesting that this was marked as the answer as it doesn't actually solve the original problem.  Also, all the `@Url.Content` portions aren't needed in MVC 4 the OP said he was using.  Instead of `<link href="@Url.Content("~/css/style.css")" rel="stylesheet"/>`, `@Styles.Render("~/css/style.css")` would be better, but even `<link href="~/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet"/>` works.

Answer (score 4):

Not easily, and I haven't run into a situation yet where it is needed since the paths are relative to the stylesheet (not the page, which may change).  Although, instead of using an absolute path like `url('/Images/bg04.png')` you should use a relative url, like `url('../Images/bg04.png')`

So if you store your CSS in `~/content` and your images are in `~/images`, then all the paths in your stylesheet should begin with `../images/`

Comment: By not easily, I mean you could, but it would be bad for performance, require additional hooks and executing a lot of code when I haven't found a good reason to go that route instead of just using relative paths.  You might be able to do something similar by hooking to the bundling and minification process and writing your own custom bundler if you really have a valid reason beyond not understanding relative paths.

Answer (score 3):

I have no problems using @Url.Content() internally in the MVC5 Razor `<head>'s <style type="text/css">` element:

> background: url('@Url.Content("~/Content/Images/logo-bg.jpg")') no-repeat scroll 0 0;