# CSS Custom property Url isn't working in Asp .Net

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, url, css-variables

I'm trying to style some cards in an mvc project and i have a custom property(variable) in my css "--bg-img" file as shown :

```
 background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, var(--bg-filter-opacity)), rgba(0, 0, 0, var(--bg-filter-opacity))), var(--bg-img);
```

and in the cshtml file my code looks like this :

```
<a class="card-posting-link posting-links" asp-action="details" asp-route-id="@item.Id" style="--bg-img: url('../../wwwroot/Uploads/@item.ImagePath')">
```

in vs code everything is fine, example :

```
<a class="card-posting-link posting-links" href="/#/" style="--bg-img: url(/Assets/image.jpeg)">
```

I tried:

~/Uploads

~/wwwroot/Uploads

and many other ways to get the images but nothing worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Solution was to add c# Url.Content bewfore the css adding the css url like this :

```
href="@Url.Content("~/wwwroot/Uploads/@item.ImagePath")" />
```

You can check the following link:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/48386317/15091527